# Maximum height for an Image in a Row on Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, size, row, height

In my example below, I need the image on the right to be the same height as the text.

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text("Intellectum est enim\n"
          " mihi quidem in multis,\n"
          " et maxime\n"
          " in me ipso, sed paulo\n"
          " ante in omnibus, cum M. \n"
          "Marcellum senatui reique\n"
          " publicae concessisti, \n"
          "commemoratis praesertim\n"
          " offensionibus, te \n"
          "auctoritatem huius ordinis\n"
          " dignitatemque rei \n"
          "publicae tuis vel doloribus\n"
          " vel suspicionibus \n"
          "anteferre. Ille quidem\n"
          " fructum omnis ante actae",
      ),
      Image.network("https://feelloo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/chat-collier-WEB-1.jpg", height: 200,)
    ],
  )
);
```

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgvrN.png)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding an interesting answer to the problem here https://www.thiscodeworks.com/how-to-make-height-of-all-widgets-inside-row-equal-the-tallest-widget-dart-flutter-layouts/5e28982bf73be40014ce9a34

Just use the following lines

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
  child: IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
          Text(
            "Intellectum est enim\n"
            " mihi quidem in multis,\n"
            " et maxime\n"
            " in me ipso, sed paulo\n"
            " ante in omnibus, cum M. \n"
            "Marcellum senatui reique\n"
            " publicae concessisti, \n"
            "commemoratis praesertim\n"
            " offensionibus, te \n"
            "auctoritatem huius ordinis\n"
            " dignitatemque rei \n"
            "publicae tuis vel doloribus\n"
            " vel suspicionibus \n"
            "anteferre. Ille quidem\n"
            " fructum omnis ante actae",
          ),
        Image.network(
          "https://feelloo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/chat-collier-WEB-1.jpg",
          height: 20,
        )
      ],
    )
  )
);
```

Thank all for your help :)

Comment: Did I test correctly so that the height I set for the image needs always to be smaller as the text? So I guess it makes sense to just set it to 1. But: works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with BoxConstraints.

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200), //this line
                      child: Text(
                        "Intellectum est enim\n"
                        " mihi quidem in multis,\n"
                        " et maxime\n"
                        " in me ipso, sed paulo\n"
                        " ante in omnibus, cum M. \n"
                        "Marcellum senatui reique\n"
                        " publicae concessisti, \n"
                        "commemoratis praesertim\n"
                        " offensionibus, te \n"
                        "auctoritatem huius ordinis\n"
                        " dignitatemque rei \n"
                        "publicae tuis vel doloribus\n"
                        " vel suspicionibus \n"
                        "anteferre. Ille quidem\n"
                        " fructum omnis ante actae",
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.network(
                      "https://feelloo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/chat-collier-WEB-1.jpg",
                      height: 200,
                    )
                  ],
                )),
```

Comment: It's not great solution, if I do this, I truncate the text display.

Comment: You can try it with the AutoSizeText package.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't there be an easier solution? Like some kind of height: 100%?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text/) package as [@Emir Çetin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15047718/emir-%C3%87etin) says, but you need to supplement it with `Flexible` widget:

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: AutoSizeText(
          "Intellectum est enim mihi quidem in multis, et maxime in me ipso, sed paulo ante in omnibus, cum M. Marcellum senatui reique publicae concessisti, commemoratis praesertim offensionibus, te auctoritatem huius ordinis dignitatemque rei publicae tuis vel doloribus vel suspicionibus anteferre. Ille quidem fructum omnis ante actae",
          maxLines: 11,
        ),
      ),
      Image.network(
        "https://feelloo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/chat-collier-WEB-1.jpg",
        height: 200,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Keep in mind that now you can have the text on one line, that is, without the `\n`.

Comment: Nice but not really what I search

Answer (score 0):

try to this:

```
    static double calculateTextHeight(
          String value, FontSize fontSize, FontWeight fontWeight, double maxWidth, int maxLines) {
        value = filterText(value);
        TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
            locale: Localizations.localeOf(GlobalStatic.context, nullOk: true),
            maxLines: maxLines,
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            text: TextSpan(
                text: value,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: fontWeight,
                  fontSize: fontSize,
                )));
        painter.layout(maxWidth: maxWidth);
        return painter.height;
      }


double _textHeight = calculateTextHeight(_msg, /* your app fontSize, fontWeight, max width of msg, maxline of msg */);
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(_msg),
      Image.network("https://feelloo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/chat-collier-WEB-1.jpg", height: _textHeight,)
    ],
  )
);
```

Comment: Nice but not really what I search